# Trouble installing homebrew package (mopidy) on new environment

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, pyenv

I recently upgraded my laptop to one of the touchbar MacBook Pros. I'm currently reconfiguring my dev environment and seem to have run into a little issue with `brew`, `python`, and perhaps `pyenv` too.

The stack trace I am getting from trying to run `brew install mopidy` is the following:

1. Command executed: `==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mopidy/2.2.1`
2. Error: [Homebrew python stacktrace screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdnLC.png)

As you can probably tell, the version of Python in which homebrew is using apparently does not have `setuptools` installed. I have done the following:

- Installed python3 and python2 with `pyenv` and installed python3 with `brew`

Then:

- set up `pyenv` with 2.7 and 3.7.1 | `pyenv versions`:

  - `system`
  - `* 2.7.5 (set by /Users/adonis/.pyenv/version`
  - `3.7.1`
- I have `brew link`'d everything `brew doctor` told me to

  - [Current `brew doctor` output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ptpR.png)
- I have attempted the following pip commands:

  - `pip install setuptools`
  - `pip3 install setuptools`
  - `pip3.7 install setuptools`
  - Also have tried using `sudo -H pip install`
- Worth noting that the only Python directories in `/usr/local/Cellar/` are the following (`ls /usr/local/Cellar | grep python`):

  - `gst-python`
  - `python`
  - `python@2`

I have exhausted google and SO for answers and the majority of accepted solutions include either specifying the pip version when using the install command or installing it globally. Not a lot of discussion of this issue on OS X. I am very confused and would like some help! Thanks.